# Sum of one column as another column in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpgrid

Using phpmyadmin I am trying to make the sum of one column "PointsAwarded" in one table "tasks" be the values in another column "points" in another table "users". Each user will get points for a task, i want to be able to have the total points they have received be a column in the "user" table. Or an alternative way to show this data in my php datagrid.

```
new C_DataGrid("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Points FROM users", "id", 
"Ranking");
```

that is the format of the datagrid I am using, it is a phpGrid format. Any help is much appreciated and any further info you need just ask.

Here is the ranking.php page

```
<?php
// use phpGrid\C_DataGrid;

include_once("../phpGrid/conf.php");
include_once('../inc/head.php');
?>

<h1><a href="../index.php">Staff Rank - Project Management System</a></h1>

<?php
$_GET['currentPage'] = 'ranking';
include_once('../inc/menu.php');
?>

<h3>Ranking</h3>

<?php
$dgRank = new C_DataGrid("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Points FROM 
users", "id", "Ranking");
$dgRank->set_col_hidden('id');
$dgRank-> set_sortname('id');
$dgRank->enable_edit();
$dgRank -> display();
?>

<?php
include_once('../inc/footer.php');
?>
```

Image Album of Database Structure/Relationship https://i.stack.imgur.com/jENvR.jpg

Album of databases and application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO8Fg.jpg

Comment: _Note:_ PHPMyAdmin is simply a web based management tool for MySQL databases. Unless you're actually in that application or changing the core files, I'm guessing that you mean to say MySQL (which is the actual database)?

Comment: Please show us what your tables look like (columns etc), some example data and the expected result.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Added some images

Comment: Please upload the images using the image button in the editor so they can be shown inline instead. Also, you still need to show us example data and the expected result. It's still pretty unclear what you want to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added more images and the php associated with displaying the table, I can't inline images as I am a new user. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a purely database design issue.

Considering that the `Points` are computed from another table, you should not have this column on your user table. You can DROP it.

The points should be computed in SQL. There are multiple ways to do this and here's an example.

Create a VIEW that computes the points for all users, based on the PointsAwarded for their tasks.
Launch this query in phpmyadmin :

```
CREATE VIEW User_Points AS
SELECT  u.id, SUM(COALESCE(t.PointsAwarded,0)) AS Points 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON u.id=t.EmployeeID
GROUP BY u.id
```

Now you can do a `SELECT * FROM User_points` and that will return something like this:

```
id  Points
1   48
2   0
3   256
4   125
```

with id being the id of the user.

Now in the PHP, change your query to this :

```
SELECT u.id, u.FirstName, u.LastName, p.Points FROM users u INNER JOIN User_points p ON u.id=p.id
```

and all your issues will be solved

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to make a few edits to your answer but got it working. Means a lot that you took your time to help! Can you just explain the last query to me so I know for the future?

Comment: @JustShiney the last query is just a JOIN between the `user` table and the `user_points` view, in order to retrieve the user points.